# How to resize image based on height size without affecting parent element width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a two column fixed menu layout, with two items on the opposite site of the screen. However, by making the image element "nav__logo" responsive using {height:100%;width:auto}, its parent element is resized to take up to much width which affects the other element (shown with black border). How do I prevent this from happening?

P.S. I want to find a solution using flexbox and not use float.

```css
*{
    border: 1px black solid;
}


.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}



.nav__logo{
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 1.7em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav__linkWrap{
    display: flex;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1.7 em;
}

.nav__linkWrap__link{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 1.7em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
        <div class="nav">
            <div>
                <img class="nav__logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="" id="header-img" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav__linkWrap">
                    <a href="#sect1" class="nav-link nav__linkWrap__link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect2" class="nav-link nav__linkWrap__link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect3" class="nav-link nav__linkWrap__link">Click Me</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I guess a better question would be why does width:auto for .nav__logo takes up so much space instead of just taking enough for image inside it.

Answer (score 0):

change the height of .nav_logo to 100px which is the height of you navbar

```css
*{
    border: 1px black solid;
}


.nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}



.nav__logo{
  height: 100%;
  
  padding: 1.7em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav__linkWrap{
    display: flex;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1.7 em;
}

.nav__linkWrap__link{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 1.7em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
            
                <img class="nav__logo" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="" id="header-img" >
           
            <div>
                <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav__linkWrap">
                    <a href="#sect1" class="nav-link nav__linkWrap__link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect2" class="nav-link nav__linkWrap__link">Click Me</a>
                    <a href="#sect3" class="nav-link nav__linkWrap__link">Click Me</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this solution responsive? You just fix the .nav__logo height to 100px,  but .nav height is a variable and can change.

Comment: solution updated.  leave height at 100% but remove width:auto from .nav_logo

Comment: updated again!  you had an extra div around your image tag.  just remove it.